# How to compile clang to use as compiler for avr?

Tags: gcc, clang, cross-compiling, avr

I'd like to cross-compile clang to use as compiler for avr (arduino to be more detailed). i feel i should do smth like next:

1. create standalone toolchain from android ndk
2. compile with correct CC and CXX parameters.

Smth else? Does it support --target=avr or how can i compile? Does it make sense as it will be used like IDE autocompletion tool to parse the sources using clang-c API?

UPDATE: configuration with --host and --target params:

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-androideabi
export CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}-gcc
export CXX=${CROSS_COMPILE}-g++
export NDK=/softdev/android-ndk-r8e
export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/softdev/android-ndk-r8e
export SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-8/arch-arm
export PATH=/softdev/arm-toolchain/bin:$PATH:/softdev/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-8/arch-arm

./configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi --target=arm-linux-androideabi --prefix=/softdev/arduinodroid_clang/arm
 make
```

... leads to make error (Makefile exists):

```
llvm asmirnov$ sudo make
llvm[0]: Constructing LLVMBuild project information.
configure: error: Already configured in /Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/llvm
make[1]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make: *** [cross-compile-build-tools] Error 1
```

Comment: where u got source-code? can u tell which version are u compiling?

Comment: i've followed official llvm getting started steps and extracted it from svn. Now i'm trying to cross-compile it not using standalone ndk toolchain and i'm getting another error: ld: unknown option: --version-script=/Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/llvm/autoconf/ExportMap.map
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [/Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/llvm_build/Release+Asserts/bin/FileCheck] Error 1
make[1]: *** [FileCheck/.makeall] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 1   this relates to cross-compilation only on macosx only

Comment: here it says http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html have u used `--with-gcc-toolchain`

Comment: According to the link "--with-gcc-toolchain" is needed to point where libstdc++ is installed. How can it relates to my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current set of [targets](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/lib/Target/) in the LLVM repository does not include AVR.  This does not mean that there has been no work done towards compiling for AVR, just that it is not in the official source repository.

For documentation on adding a backend to LLVM go [here](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMBackend.html).

Comment: @4ntoine: Very cool, but it hasn't had a commit since February 21st, 2014.

Comment: it's not my repo, so i'm not sure

Comment: You can look at the commit history and see when the last commit was and how often commits happen.

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/dylanmckay/llvm. It's actively developed by Dylan, join the project

Comment: https://github.com/avr-llvm/llvm appears to be very active and with the help of gcc-avm's linker can go all the way to binaries.

Comment: as of 2017, an AVR target has been officially added to LLVM

Answer (score 7):

LLVM contains AVR target since some time now (see http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/lib/Target/AVR/).
The skeleton was added in late 2015 and the majority of backend implementation was done about May 2016.

As of now (2017-09-05), the README.md file says that this target is still experimental and done for a 8-bit Atmel AVR microcontroller.