# Clang compile for AVR/ARM?

Tags: arm, clang, llvm, cross-compiling, avr

I'd like to cross-compile Clang for run on ARM devices and compile for ARM mcu (Cortex M3) or ATmega AVR mcus. Is Clang able to do it?

UPDATE: i've found llvm-avr backend for LLVM 3.5: 
https://github.com/sushihangover/llvm-avr

Is anyone except me interested?

Comment: Yes, [it can](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html).

Comment: What is command-line to compile "hello world" for AVR?

Comment: should i compile clang with some specific arguments to add ARM/AVR support?

Comment: thanks for explanation. i agree to have 2 versions of clang compiled for arm and for avr separately. the question is how to compile it (for avr especially)?

Comment: [If only](http://llvm.org/docs/HowToCrossCompileLLVM.html) there were [some kind](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) of [documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/HowToBuildOnARM.html) about [that](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html)...

Comment: if only someone could read its about cross-compiling on ARM but not for bare metal ARM. What about avr (arch = x86, arm, thumb, mips)?

Comment: This is a very complex issue.  See: [crosstool-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/) for scripts to build `gcc` cross compilers.  You need to build multiple compilers to make one of the two compilers you want.  Are you versed in making a compiler already?  If not, get a pre-packaged one.  If you can make a *host=build=target* compiler, then tell us specifics of your issue.

Comment: Read [crosstool-ng's how a toolchain is constructed](http://crosstool-ng.org/hg/crosstool-ng/file/99029fac116b/docs/9%20-%20How%20is%20a%20toolchain%20constructed.txt) for instance.  This is for a simple cross compiler (13 steps).  It is more complex for the type of compilers you are asking for.  The process for llvm/clang is very similar and equally arcane.  The main difference between *arm-linux* and *arm-none* (bare metal) is the 'C' library; which is part of building a compiler.

Comment: See also: [How to compile Clang for an AVR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19006000/how-to-compile-clang-to-use-as-compiler-for-avr).

Answer (score 5):

For those interested, there is a currently active fork over here:
https://github.com/dylanmckay/avr-llvm

Comment: It's about 80% ready, join the project to make it finally ready